# Black overlay showing up on top of html5 video in ie9

Tags: jquery, css, html, video, internet-explorer-9

So IE strikes again. I'm having a ridiculously hard time trying to figure out why IE is making a black screen show up on top of the video. I have a button on a web page that brings up a black div that fills the whole screen and inside the div is the video, along with a close button on the top right. The video works perfectly on all browsers, including IE9 itself. The real problem is that when I push the button that makes the div appear, it shows up all black, just like the div's background. However if I right click on the center where the video should appear and press the play option, it will begin to play and the video works fine. Yes, the video has a poster image and the controls appear on every browser, but on IE9, the controls and poster do not appear and the video screen is all black. The video even pops up when I go into the developer tools in IE9. I am simply baffled as to what kind of glitch is causing this. I even reset IE's internet options (since I work at a firm and the browsers are slightly regulated here) and nothing worked. I'm starting to think IE9 has a bad rendering issue, but idk.... here's the code:

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $("#show-video").click(function() {
    $("#presentation").css("display","block");
  });
  $("#close").click(function() {
    $("#presentation").css("display","none"); 
  });
});
```

```css
.title {
    background:
        url('http://www.sasllpcpa.com/images/sas-consulting-doctor.png') no-repeat bottom right,
        url('http://www.sasllpcpa.com/images/squared-metal.png') repeat;
    padding-top:25px;
    padding-bottom:25px;
    border-top:3px solid #111;
}

    .title h1 {
        font-size:4.32rem;
        color:#005287;
        font-family:'Open Sans', 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
        font-weigt:700;
        margin:0;
    }

    .title h2 {
        font-size:1.529rem;
        color:#111;
        margin-top:20px;
        font-style:italic;
    }

    .title .row > a {
        display:inline-block;
        padding:8px;
        background:#FFF;
        border-radius:5px;
        color:#005287;
        margin-top:100px;
        overflow:hidden;
    }

    .video-button {
        display:inline-block;
    }

    img.video-button {
        width:32px;
        border-radius:0;
        margin-right:10px;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    div.video-button { /* video icon */
        font-family:'Droid Sans', 'Arial', sans-serif;
        font-size:0.8823rem;
        font-weight:700;
        margin-top:2px;
    }

    #presentation { /* pop-up box for the video */
        position:fixed;
        background:#000;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        color:#FFF;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        z-index:1001;
        display:none;
    }

    #close {
        color:#FFF;
        font-family:'Droid Sans', 'Arial', sans-serif;
        font-weight:700;
        font-size:1.3rem;
        background:#CC0000 ;
        width:40px;
        text-align: center;
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        right:0;
    }

    .video-container {
        position:relative;
        top:10%;
        margin:auto;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        max-height:480px;
        max-width:640px;  
    }

    .title video {
        max-width:100%;
        height:100%;
        
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="title">
        <div class="row">
            <h1>SAS Consulting <br>Services, LLC</h1>
            <h2>...your dedicated healthcare trusted advisors!</h2>
            <a id="show-video" href="#presentation">
                    <img class="video-button" src="http://www.sasllpcpa.com/images/icons/video.png" alt="video"/>
                    <div class="video-button">About SAS Consulting</div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="presentation">
            <a id="close" href="#">X</a>
            <div class="video-container">
                <video id="webVideo" poster="http://www.sasllpcpa.com/images/presentation-poster.png" controls="controls">
                    <source src="http://www.sasllpcpa.com/videos/about-sas-consulting-services.mp4">
                    <source src="http://www.sasllpcpa.com/videos/About_SAS_Consulting_Services.ogv">
                    Your web browser does not support HTML5 Video.
                </video>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

(you can copy the code above on a jsfiddle, I already set it up using images and video for review [sorry if it looks a little messy, I was in a hurry]). Anyways, like I said, it works on all browsers but IE9 shows a black screen unless you right click and press play in the center of the #presentation div.

for a better view of this web page, go to http://www.sasllpcpa.com/sas_consulting/

Comment: ie9 usually shows the poster only if `preload` is set to `none`. It normally displays control buttons though (and I can see them when I run your code snippet). P.S. I changed the size of the video to a fixed value in pixels and now it shows controls

Comment: @Nadia Chibrikova hmm ok then. I'll give that a try, I was thinking of messing around more with the attributes to see if I could get it to appear. As far as the fixed value goes, Hmm... I guess I could do that, I was hoping to leave it in a percentage width, since I'm trying to fit the video to mobile devices.... maybe I'll just have to use media queries and set fixed values that way. Anyways, I have a mac at home and I'm not at the office so I'll post my results on that tomorrow morning.

Comment: I don't insist on you using fixed height, I just have an impression that the video is chopped (I don't see the lower part and it is there where the controls should be). I don't know how to fix it, since it's difficult to change the actual site and in your example controls appear all right. So it's a layout problem, try to make a small example reproducing the issue and include it in your question.

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova preload="none" worked! that's all it needed. I can see the controls as well but the weird thing is that they don't show up unless the cursor hovers over the poster. After clicking play, the controls stay fixed. I'll try and see if doing fixed values like you said will help with that, but in essence, the poster shows and the controls appear.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do anything with controls, I think what you describe is their normal behaviour. As for the size, I've got quite a small screen here, so it may cause some issues. Anyway, I'm glad it works more or less like you wanted.

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova, thanks for your help. If you wish to get credit for your solution just post the preload="none" solution below. Otherwise, I'll just put it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need so add `preload="none"` to the video element. The thing is, ie9 only shows poster before video is loaded (or started to load), so if preload is not none the image will at best flicker or not shown at all.